# How to enable paragraph indentation within minipage boxes in LyX?

Tags: lyx, minipage

In LyX, using the "Insert box" command inserts a minipage. However, this minipage does not have any paragraph indentation. Is it possible to indent all paragraphs inside minipages?

Comment: Hm, can you post some code to better understand what you are doing, or are trying to do? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`minipage`, `\parbox` and `tabular` `p` columns are all initialised by

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue
  \lineskip\normallineskip
  \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
```

with the highlighted lines setting paragraph indent and inter-paragraph spacing to 0pt.

You could redefine this (however lyx allows you to add definitions) so long as you wanted to change all those places.

If you *just* want to change `minipage` then you can define `\@minipagerestore` (which is normally just `\relax`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@minipagerestore{\setlength\parindent{1em}\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

bbb
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\linewidth}
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

bbb
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This will be a challenge with for some Lyx users ...

Comment: @MS-SPO I assume lyx has a "drop this code into the preamble" box? (but I don't have it installed to give details, if you do have lyx, or know its interface,  feel free to edit this answer or add another)